# How to achieve Ground Overlays in MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mkmapview, mapkit

I want to use ground overlays using    MKMapView    . Is it possible to do so.
Please give me a solution.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "ground overlays"?

Comment: check this following example http://www.raywenderlich.com/30001/overlay-images-and-overlay-views-with-mapkit-tutorial

Comment: Ground Overlays example - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/groundoverlay-simple. I need to develop something that is given in this using MKMapView.

Comment: I want to do the same using Aviation Style Map tiles of cropping for a farming corporation. The Sat Views by Apple & Google etc aren't up to date for the operations that go on there. So, dId you find an answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

Its a little late, but I think i found your answer. As a public service to others with the same question, but where the "Ray Wenderlich link to 6 Flags Magic Mountain MapKit Tutorial: Overlay Views" doesn't quite cut the mustard:

[Try This Link: https://www.raywenderlich.com/158175/advanced-mapkit-tutorial-custom-tiles](https://www.raywenderlich.com/158175/advanced-mapkit-tutorial-custom-tiles)  You'll need to be proficient at Graphic Line Art / illustration or trade deals with an Arts student because it involves preparing your own graphics for the actual tiles used, this is right down your alley.